# How to converts a character to decimal on progress 4GL?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cDateTime AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt_data NO-UNDO
    FIELD DateTime   AS DECIMAL FORMAT "->>,>>9.99".

ASSIGN
cDateTime = "20191604121566".

CREATE tt_data.
ASSIGN
tt_data.DateTime = DECIMAL(cDateTime) /* Message Date and Time */
```

But it says:

"Value cannot be displayed using  ->>>,>>>,>>9.999999".

Could you please help this case and tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Can I get answer for my question please?

Comment: Nobody is being paid to monitor this site and immediately respond to questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code that you show does not result in the error that you are reporting.

I'm guessing that you have a DISPLAY statement somewhere in your real code.

The reported error simply means that that DISPLAY format is not wide enough for the data.  By default DISPLAY will use whatever format you specified in the definition of a data element.  If you did not specify anything then every datatype also has a default.  For decimals the default is "->>,>>>.99".

You can either increase the format in the definition or override it in the display statement like so:

```
display tt_data.DateTime format ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>9".
```

Note: the display format has no influence on the values that you can store in a field.  You can always "overstuff" more data into a variable than you can display.  The format is only for output display purposes -- it has nothing to do with storage.

Answer (score 3):

The assignment works fine, however the display not.

So ...

```
DISPLAY tt_data.DateTime.
```

... does not work because it uses format "->>,>>9.99".

You can change the format in the definition, for example "99999999999999", or do:

```
DISPLAY tt_data.DateTime FORMAT "99999999999999".
```